# Android: Only the last row of my ListView is reacting to an OnClickListener

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, onclicklistener

I have a `ListView` with a View Holder. When I press a button in one of the rows of my `ListView` it's supposed to expand the row at that position and collapse when I press it again. I do this using show/hide on the layouts. However the click is not expanding the correct rows.

**Example:**

```
I was clicked
I am a row that was not clicked
I am a row that was not clicked
I am a row that was not clicked // yet my layout was shown and hidden
```

This happens anytime I scroll, only the last row that's visible in my `ListView` will react to any row I press.

**Code**

```
public class PetAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
...
...

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mPetList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (mPetList.get(position).getPetType().equals(ConstantValues.CAT)) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mPetList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return Integer.parseInt(mPetList.get(position).getId());
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Pet pet;
        View view = convertView;

        switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
            case 0:
                pet = mPetList.get(position);
                mRowType = ConstantValues.CAT;
                view = createCatRow(pet, convertView, parent);
                break;
            case 1:
                pet = mPetList.get(position);
                mRowType = ConstantValues.DOG;
                view = createDogRow(pet, convertView, parent);
                break;
        }

        return view;
    }
```

**Inflate Row**

```
    public View createCatRow(Pet pet, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView != null) {
            mCatHolder = (CatViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        } else {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.cat_row, parent, false);
            mCatHolder= new CatViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(mCatHolder);
        }

        setCatText(pet);
        setCatListeners(pet);

        return convertView;
    }
```

**Set Text**

```
    public void setCatText(Pet pet) {
        mCatHolder.catName.setText(pet.getName());         
    }
```

**Set Listener**

```
public void setCatListeners(Pet pet) {      
    mCatHolder.catName.setOnClickListener(getCatNameListener(pet));
}

public View.OnClickListener getCatNameListener(final Pet pet) {
     return new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             expandCard(pet);
         }
     };
}
```

**SetVisibility**

```
public void expandCard(Pet pet) {
    if (mCatHolder.expanded.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
        mCatHolder.collapsed.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mCatHolder.expanded.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        mCatHolder.collapsed.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mCatHolder.expanded.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

**View Holder**

```
public static class CatViewHolder {            
    @Bind(R.id.expanded) RelativeLayout expanded;
    @Bind(R.id.collapsed ) RelativeLayout collapsed;
    @Bind(R.id.cat_name) TextView catName;

    public CatViewHolder(View view) {
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    }
}
```

Please help me understand why this behavior is happening. Why does the last row react to OnClick events from the first row. Thank you

Comment: I will try this. It does make for a bit of similar methods though. Since I have two layouts it means I have to filter each method with a conditional statement or I have to create two methods for each type even though they do the same thing

Comment: are you holding reference to the holder in your adapter class? that usually doesnt work well. Instead of holding the viewholder as a reference why not pass it through your functions? You know there is only one instance of the adapter class per list view right?

Comment: @Bhargav yep, I just thought it would be easier then passing it through each function. Refactoring now to try

Comment: @Rah ty you were right

Comment: @Bhargav it worked by making it local and passing it through each time

Comment: @i_me_mine im going to make this into an answer, select it as the right one instead of the recycler view bindviewholder answer which doesnt have anything to do with this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `RecyclerView`, views are recycled. So the view from the first row is re-used for later rows and it still has it's `OnClickListener`. You have to set the listener in *every* `onBindViewHolder()`.

Comment: I believe I am doing that. If not please show me how I'm breaking the view holder pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You are holding reference to your viewholder in the adapter class, and then applying the onClicklistener to the view. This means the viewholder variable will be referencing the last view rendered, along with setting the onclicklistener to the last view rendered.

You need make the viewholder reference a local variable in your getview method and pass it to all your functions which require the view holder.